# Html button without text rendered not like with text

Tags: html, css

Html button element for exemple 5 buttons in row rendered different,
buttons with text rendered in the same top position but buttons without text
 rendered little upper.
Lets i show you
https://jsfiddle.net/zznjrv9L/
html

```
<button>234</button>
<button></button>
<button>234</button>
<button>234</button>
<button></button>
```

css

```
 button{
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
  }
```

I tryed it in Chrome.
How do i fix it that all buttons renders on same top position?

Comment: just put vertical-align: top; for buttons

Answer (score 7):

Use inline-block for the buttons and use top/middle/bottom for its consistancy:

```
button{
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zznjrv9L/2/)

Comment: Also, put width=auto so that your text reside in button area.

Comment: @Atula I wouldn't. The OP is just trying to know the alignment for buttons with text and without text. OP may put lesser text there and want a fixed width.

Comment: It was only a suggestion

Comment: @Atula Yeah. Leave it for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons with text use the text to calculate their alignment. Button without text has no such information are aligned in other ways. It seems you have to put at least one character to a button to align it properly. One option is to put a space with no width (use code or name):

```html
<button></button>
<button>&#8203;</button>
<button>234</button>
<button>&ZeroWidthSpace;</button>
```